# How can I lock and start screensaver on my MacBook Pro simultaneously without hot corners?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac, mojave

I am having trouble locking my screen and starting my screen saver on my MacBook Pro simultaneously without using hot corners.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not done this, but you can set up an automator service to trigger your screensaver with a shortcut from the keyboard.

Here is a link:

http://osxdaily.com/2014/07/10/set-screen-saver-keyboard-shortcut-mac/